# C++17: call base class and delegated constuctor in the initializer list

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, c++17

I have a class `B` which consists of a bunch of data members which I'd like to initialize upon construction.

However, the argument needed for their initialization is

- a costly function to compute
- depends on a base class data member

I am looking for a way to compute the argument just once and initialize all data members in the initializer list.

In the schematic example below all data members of a class `B` require a `Temp()` call to be performed. The latter call depends on the base class variable. Hence I'd like call both base class and delegated constructor together but that's not possible as per C++ rules.

```cpp
struct A {
    int value_;

    A(int v) : value_{v + 1} {};
};

struct B : public A {
  double value1_;
  double value2_;
  double value3_;

  double Temp() const {return 0.5 + A::value_;}

  B(int v) : A(v), B(Temp()) {}; // ERROR: this is illegal as per C++ standard

 private:
  B(double temp)
    : value1_{temp}
    , value2_{temp}
    , value3_{temp} {};
};
```

Comment: if your example is representative of your actual code you could just assign to the values in the body of the constructor

Comment: Unfortunately, in the actual code those data members are not `double`, hence I'd like to avoid default initialization as well.

Comment: `B(int v) : A(v), value1_(Temp()), value2_(value1_), value3_(value1_) {}` Be careful to list members in the initializer list in the same order they appear in the class definition.

Comment: Or, wrap the three `valueX_` members in a helper class, that `B` either derives from (possibly privately) or holds as a member. Give that helper class an appropriate constructor, pass `Temp()` to it from `B`'s initializer list.